# Mesmo conjunto de caracteres gerando hashs diferentes após conversão com MD5()

Tags: php

Olá, estou criando um sistema que possui uma área de inscrição do usuário no sistema. Na parte da senha eu utilizo md5() para transformar os caracteres em Hash.

Só que eu estou notando o seguinte, as vezes eu insiro um conjunto de caracteres e o mesmo conjunto de caracteres está sendo armazenados e exibidos com hashes(não sei se é esse o plural) diferente.

Por exemplo: O conjunto de caracteres 505987.

**No Banco de Dados ele me dá o seguinte hash:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora se eu der uma echo desse campo no meu PHP dá a seguinte saída:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se isso é normal ?

E gostaria de saber também se eu fosse talvez fazer um comparativo entre esses dois dados em algum momento, poderia dar erro ou passaria de boa.

Pode um mesmo conjunto de caracteres terem Hashes diferentes ?

Desculpem se não consegui ser claro.

**ATUALIZANDO:** Parece que quando eu digito no form gera um Hash direferente do que quando eu faço uma consulta no banco, pego esse campo que possui o hash armazenado e armazeno em uma variável e depois exibo essa variável.

Comment: Algoritmos de hash são aplicado a bits.. se vocês fizer hash de um número inteiro ou de uma string que representa este número, os resultados serão diferentes pois a representação deste valores em bits são diferentes. Dito isso, a maneira como strings são convertidas em bits depende do encoding. Seria legal você checar se o tipo de dados é o mesmo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma valor deve mapear apenas para um campo de hash, porém um hash pode apontar para várias senhas.
Por exemplo, o hash de uma senha como "vi7700" pode ser igual a um hash de uma senha como "d3f3q8", porém um texto só aponta para um hash.

No seu caso, o hash que está armazenado no banco de dados é o correto, então tenha certeza que ao criar uma hash você está limpando os espaços vazios, use o `trim` para isso.

Rodando aqui na minha máquina o seguinte código

```
<?php

 if(md5('505987') == 'b969d7036923881b0cb18539a7b15e7c'){
    echo "Elas são iguais";
 }
```

O resultado foi o esperado.

Comment: Tomara que o trim resolva. Vou tentar fazer amanhã e te dou um feedback.

Comment: O trim não era o problema, @Hítalo. Mas mesmo assim agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso utilize o trim() ou str_replace() nas aspas simples e duplas.

Um adendo, notei que está utilizando MD5() como senha

> Na parte da senha eu utilizo md5()

O correto neste caso é utilizar-se de um *salt*, adicionar um valor de controle nas senhas para que o hash não retorne a senha direto, pois há diversos sites que utilizam Rainbow Tables ou Hash Tables que podem quebrar MD5 facilmente.
Dê uma pesquisada no conceito para melhor utilização.